# VBA Macro to filter a table by specific cell value and delete all rows

Tags: excel, vba, filter, datatable

The intention of my macro is to perform the following steps:
 1: Filter table looking at column D to retrieve all "0" values
 2: Delete all rows with "0" values
 3: Remove filter.

The issue is that my table has 75,000+ rows of data so I keep getting alerts saying I have too much data. I tried a loop macro but it was taking too long to perform the job so I am now working on a macro that performs the above steps. My code keeps getting hung up on the line to delete the range of cells I selected. (my range goes  past the table range because this table will always have a variable amount of rows).

Error: "Method 'Range' of oject'_Worksheet' failed

I am assuming that I need to specify the exact number of rows in my table. How do I change the code so that I do not have to change the range every time I perform the macro?

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub Delete_Zero_Rows()

Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Status")
  ws.Activate

  On Error Resume Next
    ws.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0
  ws.Range("B3:F1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="0"


  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws.Range("B4:F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  On Error Resume Next
    ws.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Are there more than 6 columns with data and are there formulas? A faster solution might be to copy the complete data set into an array, manipulate it there and copy it back to the range and delete the last consecutive rows in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A loop should work fine with 75,000 rows. Turning off screen updating to speed it up.  Try this:

```
Sub DeleteZeroRows()
    Dim LastRow As Long, n As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    For n = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(n, 5).Value = 0 Then Cells(n, 5).EntireRow.Delete
    Next n
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note that I'm stepping backwards (bottom up) so when the row is deleted and shifted up it doesn't change the row number you move to in the next loop iteration.

Also note `Cells(n, 5)` where `5` is the column ("E") and is where I'm looking for zeros.

Comment: This macro works when I step through it but my excel file froze after I actually ran it. The workbook is currently at 13,650 KB... The table is also hooked up to over a dozen pivot tables - do you think that could slow it down?

Comment: @BrandonM. Yes, that may make a difference.  Not sure if this would solve that problem with pivot tables but try also changing calculation mode to manual before the loop and back to automatic after the loop.  `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`

Comment: I inserted the calculation mode from manual to automatic after loop like you said. I also deleted a few connections that weren't necessary and a miscellaneous tab that had unnecessary data. I am now at 3,543 KB but it is still running painfully slow. I let the macro finish its job and it took almost 5 minutes. Any ideas on how to speed it up?

Comment: Not sure my answer deserves the check mark if it's still too slow for you.  Maybe @DavidZemens can help a bit more.  He has a lot more experience with large files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter on column “D” then it’s the third one when starting from column “B”

```
Sub Main
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Status")
        .ShowAllData
        With .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="0"
            On Error Resume Next
            .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
           On Error GoTo 0
        End With 
        .AutofilterMode = False
    End With 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

## Modify Range in Array

- The following code only works if there are values in the range, **not
  formulas**. If there are formulas, values will be returned.
- The following code will copy the entire range into an array, where it
  will check each row for the criteria and if not found, will
  (over)write to the same array resulting in a too big array, but will
  then in 1 of 3 possible ways (`cWriteDelete`) write back to the
  range:

  1. It will write empty strings (**""**) to the remainder of the array and
     paste it back to the range.
  2. It will copy the array as is into the range and delete the
     unnecessary **rows**.
  3. It will copy the array as is into the range and delete the
     unnecessary **range**.
- **Why not resize the array?**

  The array is a **2D** array, and we cannot resize its first dimension (**rows**).

### The Code

```
Sub Delete_Zero_Rows()

    Const cSheet As String = "Status"       ' Worksheet Name
    Const cRange As String = "A:F"          ' Source Columns Range Address
    Const cFR As Long = 4                   ' First Row Number
    Const cCol As Variant = "E"             ' Criteria Column Letter/Number
    Const cCrit As Long = 0                 ' Criteria
    Const cWriteDelete As Long = 2          ' 1 - Write "" to array
                                            ' 2 - Delete remaining rows
                                            ' 3 - Delete remaining range

    Dim Rng As Range      ' Last Used Cell Range In Criteria Column,
                          ' Source/Target Range
    Dim vntST As Variant  ' Source/Target Array
    Dim ACC As Long       ' Array Criteria Column Number
    Dim i As Long         ' Source Array Row Counter
    Dim j As Long         ' Source/Target Array Column Counter
    Dim k As Long         ' Target Array Row Number (Counter)

    ' Speed up.
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    On Error GoTo ProcedureExit   ' Safely exit program.

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet)

        '************************************************
        ' Last Used Cell Range in Criteria Column (Rng) '
        '************************************************

        ' Calculate Last Used Cell Range in Criteria Column.
        Set Rng = .Columns(cCol).Find("*", , xlFormulas, _
                xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
        ' Check if all cells in Criteria Column (cCol) are empty i.e. Last Used
        ' Cell Range in Criteria Column (Rng) is Nothing.
        If Rng Is Nothing Then  ' Inform user.
            MsgBox "No Data in Column '" & Split(.Cells(1, cCol).Address, _
                    "$")(1) & "'.", vbInformation, "Empty Column"
            GoTo ProcedureExit  ' Safely exit program.
        End If

        '******************************
        ' Source (Target) Range (Rng) '
        '******************************

        ' Calculate Source/Target Range (Rng) from Source Columns Range(cRange).
        Set Rng = .Columns(cRange).Resize(Rng.Row - cFR + 1).Offset(cFR - 1)
        ' Copy Source/Target Range (Rng) to Source/Target Array (vntST).
        vntST = Rng

        '******************************
        ' Source/Target Array (vntST) '
        '******************************

        ' Calculate Array Criteria Column Number.
        ACC = .Columns(cCol).Column
        ' Loop through rows (i) of Source/Target Array (vntST).
        For i = 1 To UBound(vntST)
            ' Check if value of current row (i) in Array Criteria Column (ACC)
            ' does not equal to Criteria  (cCrit).
            If vntST(i, ACC) <> cCrit Then
                ' Count (add 1 to) Target Array Row Number (k).
                k = k + 1
                ' Loop through columns(j) of Source/Target Array (vntST).
                For j = 1 To UBound(vntST, 2)
                    ' Write from current row(i) in column(j) to current row(k)
                    ' in column (j) of Source/Target Array (vntST).
                    ' Note: Data is being overwritten since always k <= j.
                    vntST(k, j) = vntST(i, j)
                Next
            End If
        Next
        ' Check if Target Array Row Number is equal to the number of rows in
        ' Source/Target Array (or in Source/Target Range).
        If k = UBound(vntST) Then ' or k = Rng.Rows.Count; Inform user.
            MsgBox "No cell containing '" & cCrit & "' in Column '" _
                    & Split(.Cells(1, cCol).Address, "$")(1) & "' found.", _
                    vbInformation, "Nothing Changed"
            GoTo ProcedureExit  ' Safely exit program.
        End If

        Select Case cWriteDelete
            Case 1  ' Slower version.
                ' Loop through the remaining rows (i) of Source/Target
                ' Array (vntST) starting from the current Target Array Row
                ' Number (k) increased by 1 (next).
                For i = k + 1 To UBound(vntST)
                    ' Loop through columns(j) of Source/Target Array (vntST).
                    For j = 1 To UBound(vntST, 2)
                        ' Write empty strings ("") to current row(i) in
                        ' column (j) of Source/Target Array (vntST)
                        vntST(i, j) = ""
                    Next
                Next

                '******************************
                ' Target (Source) Range (Rng) '
                '******************************

                ' Copy completely modified Source/Target Array (vntST)
                ' to Source/Target Range (Rng).
                Rng = vntST

            Case 2  ' Faster Version.

                '******************************
                ' Target (Source) Range (Rng) '
                '******************************

                ' Copy not completely modified Source/Target Array (vntST)
                ' to Source/Target Range (Rng).
                Rng = vntST

                ' Delete remaining (not modified) rows greater than current
                ' Target Array Row Number (k) increased by First Row (cFR),
                ' i.e. starting from the calculated row:
                ' (k + 1) + (cFR - 1) = k + cFR.
                .Rows(k + cFR & ":" & Rng.Rows.Count + cFR - 1).Delete

            Case 3  ' Faster Version.

                '******************************
                ' Target (Source) Range (Rng) '
                '******************************

                ' Copy not completely modified Source/Target Array (vntST)
                ' to Source/Target Range (Rng).
                Rng = vntST

                ' Delete remaining (not modified) range.
                .Columns(cRange).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count - k) _
                        .Offset(k + cFR - 1).Delete ' Clear, ClearContents
            Case Else

        End Select

    End With

ProcedureExit:
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```